# “Power” tags need improvement

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

There's a gap in the available tags. The only tags with “power” in the name are [power](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) and [power-supply](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply). If we believe their descriptions, then [power](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) is for RF power levels only (though it doesn't say that) and [power-supply](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply) is for, well, power supplies.

The gap in this tagging scheme is that there is no tag for questions about DC power but not power supplies (e.g. 12V power distribution). We currently have 5 such questions, 4 of which are tagged [power](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power).

I think that it would make sense to create a tag for the topic of getting power to equipment — hence including not just AC-to-DC power supplies, but wiring, solar power, interference/grounding issues in power wiring, etc.

The first name that comes to mind for such a tag would be [dc-power](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-power), which I think is pretty good, but I'd rather one that doesn't specifically exclude AC line power. (We could declare that [power-supply](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply) includes these things, following the argument I once heard that a power *supply* is not just that conversion box (a power *adapter*) but also everything connected to the input side of it, but I think that's an argument that's been lost.)

Any suggestions?

---

(I also propose to rename current [power](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) to [rf-power](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rf-power), to make misuse less likely.)

Answer (score 1):

Hearing no objections or suggestions for improvement, I have done the following:

- Renamed [power](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) to [rf-power](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rf-power).
- Where appropriate, added the tag [dc-power](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-power) and removed the tag [rf-power](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rf-power).